# Setting up https with AWS too costly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

I am trying to set up https for my EC2 instance but am very confused about the AWS Cloud HSM because it says that I have to pay an hourly rate of about $1.45 per hour, which would be $974.00 per month to have an https endpoint?!
The tutorial I am following is here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ssl-offload-enable-traffic-and-verify-certificate.html

I feel like I am missing something because I can’t imagine that to have an https certificate cost that much??
Do I have to use AWS Cloud HSM?
I have successfully imported an existing https certificate into AWS but I cannot afford this apparent cloudHSM cost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use CloudHSM for ssl certificates on regular websitess. Instead you should be use AWS ACM which provides **free SSL** certificates for use in AWS. However, ACM can't directly be used on a plain EC2 instance. You would have to use load balancer for it to work.

Thus, if you just want EC2 instance, and nothing else, you can use [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get **free SSL** cerficates for your domain which you can manually setup on your ec2 instance.